# Unknown URL Scheme

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I have an android `WebView` which prints to a receipt printer using an intent. This works fine using the chrome browser but when I open try to print using the `WebView` it gives me an error message as follows

```
Webpage not available.
The webpage at
intent://....
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.
```

I've seen the following link but i'm not sure how to implement it.
[how-to-fix-unknown-url-scheme-in-android-webview](https://www.zidsworld.com/android-development/how-to-fix-unknown-url-scheme-in-android-webview/)

I'm not an android developer. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is present in the link you provided.

> The WebView will usually recognize `http` and `https`, anything other than
>   these, for example – `intent://`,`market://`,`app://`,`mail://` etc will not
>   be *recognized* by WebView unless we add a **handler** to handle these url
>   schemes or by *disabling* these schemes and only load **http** and **https**
>   schemes.

Test this in your MainActivity. Try opening a simple *google search* window using the url in the `WebView`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  String url = "http://www.google.com";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webactivity);

    final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    webview.loadUrl(url);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        if (url.startsWith("http") || url.startsWith("https")) {
          return true;
        } else {
          webview.stopLoading();
          webview.goBack();
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unknown Link, unable to handle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```